# While Loop to calculate Number of years

Tags: java, while-loop

I am not quite sure how a while loop is relevant for this type of question. The program must ask the user to input a number of days and a number of years contained in those number of days must be returned. Anything under 365 is still considered 1 year. Must use a while loop. Description in picture. Think I have the idea, just missing something

[Program Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9aNC.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A2_Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a positive number of days n: ");
        int numberOfDays = keyboard.nextInt();
        int numberOfYears = 0;

        if (numberOfDays > 0 && numberOfDays < 365){
            numberOfYears = 1;
            System.out.printf("Number of years: " + numberOfYears );
        }

        else {

            while(numberOfDays >= 365){

                System.out.printf("Number of years: " + numberOfYears);

            }
         }
         System.out.println("Thank you for using Zach's program and goodbye !!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - it's very hard to read at the moment. And you haven't given a clear description of the problem you're facing - you've shown the code, but not told us what happens vs what's meant to happen. Finally, there's no reason to show the requirements as a picture - they're basically just text, which should be in the question.

Comment: In the `while` loop, just keep subtracting 365.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp And incrementing the number of years might also be an idea. ;)

Comment: I mean you could probably tell im a beginner programmer. First programming class i've ever taken. And subtracting 365 from what?

Comment: @911DidBush Of course. But since this looks like a homework assignment, I didn't want to give too much away.

Comment: yeah it is, at least i understand now which is most important. Did some pretty serious loops on my own for other questions, but for some reason just had trouble with this one. It was almost too simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am not quite sure how a while loop is relevant for this type of
>   question.

Your program instructions suggest that you are not allowed to use `modulo` operator. That's why as one of the alternatives, you can use a `while` loop. See the following snippet:

```
numberOfYears = 1;
while(numberOfDays >= 365){
   numberOfDays = numberOfDays - 365;
   numberOfYears++;
}

System.out.println("Number of years: " + numberOfYears);
```